# Can't open 4444 port in gufw

Tags: 14.04, ufw, port-forwarding, nmap, gufw

I've added a SSH rule for adding 4444 port in my distro through gufw but when I run

```
nmap -sV 10.9.0.136 -A
```

it shows :

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-04-25 11:30 IST
Nmap scan report for 10.9.0.136
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 10.9.0.136 are closed
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
Network Distance: 0 hops
OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.50 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong?

[gufw rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiVKz.png)

Comment: First, try with command `nmap 10.9.0.136 -P0` and give me output. Also give me output from firewall rules `sudo ufw status`

Comment: Sorry, `nmap` scan first 1024 port's, Add port range in command for scan `nmap -p 1-5000 10.9.0.136 -P0`

Comment: for sudo ufw status: `Status: active To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
10.9.0.136 4444/tcp on eth0 ALLOW       10.9.0.136 4444/tcp`

Comment: `Nmap scan report for 10.9.0.136
Host is up (0.000023s latency).
Not shown: 4999 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
538/tcp open  gdomap` still port 4444 is closed.

Comment: Are you sure that service listen for connection on port `4444`. Do you see service in listening state in output from command `netstat -atpn`?

Comment: no, there is no service listening on port 4444.

Comment: i've an image for `gufw rule`, please check it out

Comment: Is your sshd_config configured to use port 4444? You can't expect a port to be open if nothing is opening it. All that firewall rule is doing is allowing access through the port, not opening it.

Comment: You need a service configured to listen or use the port in order for the port to be opened. If you configure ssh to use port 4444 for example, the port would then be opened, and your firewall rule would allow connections to that port.

Answer (score 0):

"By default, Nmap scans the most common 1,000 ports for each protocol. "

Try to specify -p4444

Comment: `Nmap scan report for 10.9.0.136
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
4444/tcp closed krb524`